# SQL CTE Recursive Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I am trying to read from Sql a virtual file system structure.  I would like to be able to use the child/parent recurse, but then be able to change a folder name and then all children from the old folder name show the new folder name.

--Create temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE #Objects (
    child VARCHAR(20),
    parent VARCHAR(20),
    ObjectType int
)
```

--Insert some rows

```
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('Folder1',NULL,1)
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('File1','Folder1',0)
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('File2','Folder1',0)
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('Folder2','Folder1',1)  -- Folder1 gets renamed to Folder2
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('File3','Folder2',0)
```

--Try to recurse

```
;WITH cteLevelOne (parent, child, Depth) AS
(
        SELECT a.parent, a.child, 1 as Depth
        FROM #Objects AS a
        WHERE ObjectType = 1  -- Folder
            AND Parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL

        SELECT a.parent, a.child, c.Depth + 1 as Depth
        FROM #Objects AS a
        INNER JOIN cteLevelOne AS c ON a.child = c.parent 
        WHERE ObjectType = 0 -- File
)

select * from CTELevelone
```

Output received

```
parent  child   Depth
NULL    Folder1 1
```

required output (files and their current folder)

```
--Folder2   File1
--Folder2   File2
--Folder2   File3
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: the support for this is long gone, maybe a newer version would be better

Comment: thanks, you mean this is easier in later versions?

Comment: no old versions are unsecure and don't get updates, so they should be repaced.

Comment: That's not really a hierarchy though, i'm not sure what it is, something like a edge node graph thing

Comment: I don't understand: `Folder2` only contains 1 file why are you expecting the other two when they are actually part of `Folder1`? Either way: your join is backwards, and the `WHERE ObjectType = 0` predicate should be on the outside of the CTE. And it's not clear why you need to recurse at all, why not just select directly from the table? https://dbfiddle.uk/QXojaNff

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 2008 r2 any more for some years, but i would repace first the names and then make the recursive CTE

```
WITH First_rename as (
  SELECT child, Parent FROM #Objects          
  WHERE ObjectType = 1  -- Folder
            AND Parent IS NOT NULL),
  replace_folder as (
  SELECT COALESCE(f1.child,o.child) [child],COALESCE(f.child,o.parent) [parent],ObjectType
   fROM #Objects o LEFT JOIN First_rename f ON o.parent = f.parent
  LEFT JOIN First_rename f1 ON o.child = f1.parent
  )
,
cteLevelOne (parent, child, Depth) as 
(
        SELECT a.parent, a.child, 1 as Depth
        FROM replace_folder AS a
        WHERE ObjectType = 1  -- Folder
            AND Parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL

        SELECT a.parent, a.child, c.Depth + 1 as Depth
        FROM replace_folder AS a
        INNER JOIN cteLevelOne AS c ON c.child = a.parent 
        WHERE ObjectType = 0 -- File
)

select * from CTELevelone WHERE Parent is  NOT NULL
```

| parent | child | Depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Folder2 | File1 | 2 |
| Folder2 | File2 | 2 |
| Folder2 | File3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dwK9i4yY)

Comment: That seems to be along the right track but if I then rename the folder again:

INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('Folder3','Folder2',1)
INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) VALUES ('File4','Folder3',0)

it stays as Folder2 :/

Comment: sql goes from row to row, you can programm lops, but i recommend to do that in a languas like python or php

Comment: also you have no order column, so as Tables are unsorted even an algorithm could run

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Objects (
    child VARCHAR(20),
    parent VARCHAR(20),
    ObjectType int
)

INSERT INTO #Objects (child,parent,ObjectType) 
VALUES ('Folder1',NULL,1)
,('File1','Folder1',0)
,('File2','Folder1',0)
,('Folder2','Folder1',1)  -- Folder1 gets renamed to Folder2
,('File3','Folder2',0)
,('Folder3','Folder2',1)
,('File4','Folder3',0) 
,('Folder4',NULL,1)
,('Folder5',NULL,1)
,('Folder6','Folder5',1)
,('File5','Folder5',0) 
,('File6','Folder6',0) 

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  child AS path, child AS parent
    ,   1 AS level
    FROM    #objects so
    WHERE   parent IS NULL
    AND ObjectType = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.path, o.child
    ,   level + 1
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN #Objects o
        ON  o.parent = c.parent
        AND ObjectType = 1
    )
SELECT  o.child, latest.parent as filePath
FROM    #Objects o
INNER JOIN cte c -- Get the real parent
    ON  c.parent = o.parent
CROSS apply (   -- Get the most recent level for the path
        SELECT  TOP 1 parent
        FROM    cte c2
        WHERE   c2.path = c.path
        ORDER BY level DESC
    ) latest
WHERE   o.ObjectType = 0
```

I create a cte which builds a original root folder for each path. Then for each file, one can go through the parent folder back to original root folder, and finally get the most recent folder name for the original root.

Comment: thazt gives teh same result as mine https://dbfiddle.uk/arRIv_Ip

Comment: Hmm, yeah, but not if i add the sample data from my code?

Comment: thanks all this is exactly what I wanted to do, knew it could be done but how, thank you everyone

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer that was helpful in answering your question, it's both a way of saying thanks and for others to know what the solution was